# How to set custom redirect url in register in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I overwrite register method in `RegistersUsers` Trait in `RegisterController` to this :

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'username' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:8|confirmed',
        'phone_number' => [
            'required',
            'min:11',
            'max:11',
            Rule::unique('users')
        ]
    ]);

    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $request['name'],
        'password' => Hash::make($request['password']),
        'username' => $request['username']
    ]);

    $this->guard()->login($user);

    $code = ActiveCode::generateCode($user);
    $request->session()->flash('phone', $request['phone_number']);
    $request->session()->flash('auth', ['user_id' => $user->id]);

    $user->notify(new ActiveCodeNotification($code, $request['phone_number']));

    return redirect(route('register.token'));

}
```

As you can see at the end i returned to a custom route, but after registering, it will redirect to `/home`.

And this is `protected $redirectTo = '/';`

Why it can't redirect to `route('register.token')` ?

**UPDATE**

This is `register.token` route :

```
Route::get('/register/phone', 'Auth\RegisterController@showTokenForm')
->name('register.token');
```

And this is `showTokenForm` method :

```
public function showTokenForm(Request $request)
{
    $request->session()->reflash();

    return view('auth.register-token');
}
```

Comment: what is this `register.token` route and does it have a middleware assigned to it? like the `guest` middleware?  and setting `$redirectTo` won't do anything since you are manually returning the redirect response

Comment: register.token is my route name who return a blade for me

Comment: does it have the `guest` middleware assigned to it?

Comment: no, doesn't have guest

Comment: Question updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `guest` middleware is being applied to your route. Use `php artisan route:list` to see what middleware it says is attached to it. The `guest` middleware is applied to all the actions of the `RegisterController` by default, it is set in the constructor of the controller. You will have to adjust that:

```
$this->middleware('guest')->except('showTokenForm');
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```php
return redirect(route('register.token'));
```

by

```php
return redirect()->route('register.token');
```

Source:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/redirects#redirecting-named-routes